# file size increasing when while uploading and converting video to flv with ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, converters

I need to upload and convert video from any format to flv. i'm doing this with ffmpeg and using this ffmpeg  command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec flv -sameq -ar 22050  -f flv output.flv
```

this command is running fine but the problem is the file size of output file is 5 times grater than the original input file and if i reduce it it reduces the quality also, need help.

Comment: please give me the solution for convert video with same quality and size.

Comment: If you need same quality and size, easy answer is don't convert it.  Any time you convert something, you can't guarantee the same quality _and_ size.

Comment: not exactly same but its increasing 4-5 times larger, so if it would convert nearby the original that will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command reveals this

```
Option 'sameq' was removed. If you are looking for an option to preserve the
quality (which is not what -sameq was for), use -qscale 0 or an equivalent
quality factor option.
```

This worked for me instead

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec flv -q:a 0 -q:v 0 -ar 22050 -f flv output.flv
```

Comment: thanks ! will this code remain the size and quality approx equivalent to the original.